# Postgresql Parallelism compared to SQL Server

Tags: postgresql, parallel-processing

Migrating to Postgresql. So sorry if I am confused or not clear in my question.

In SQL Server, we have settings like Max Degree of parallelism which we can set at the server level, database level, query level which defines the workers/threads to be used by any node/operator in execution plan.

I have found like Max worker processes, max parallel workers, max workers per gather streams settings in Postgres which is very confusing.

Can anyone please explain these terms to me?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-ASYNC-BEHAVIOR):

> `max_worker_processes (integer)`
>
> Sets the maximum number of background processes that the system can support. [...]
>
> When changing this value, consider also adjusting `max_parallel_workers`, `max_parallel_maintenance_workers`, and `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`.
>
> `max_parallel_workers_per_gather (integer)`
>
> Sets the maximum number of workers that can be started by a single `Gather` or `Gather Merge` node. Parallel workers are taken from the pool of processes established by `max_worker_processes`, limited by `max_parallel_workers`.
>
> `max_parallel_workers (integer)`
>
> Sets the maximum number of workers that the system can support for parallel operations.

`max_worker_processes` and `max_parallel_workers` can only be set globally (on the instance level), and changing `max_worker_processes` requires a server restart. `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` can be set globally, overridden on the database level or in individual database sessions.

`max_parallel_workers` sets the limit for the number of parallel worker process that can be running at any given time in an instance, and `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` sets the limit for an individual SQL statement.

Comment: In MSSQL, we have "max number of Threads" server level configuration which indicates a shared pool of thread for Parallelism, connections etc and by default depends on Online Schedulers (default depends on number of Cores available on around 512+).  In Postgresql I dont think there's any such shared pool. Please another question is why there are 2 settings max_worker_processes and max_parallel_workers. Is it true pls confimr max_parallel_workers_per_gather  < = max_parallel_workers  <= max_worker_processes

Comment: There can be custom background worker processes that are *not* parallel workers. See the `pg_prewarm` and `pg_timetable` extensions for examples. Hence the different limits.